# different ip to connect to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, ip, database-connection

When I want to connect to mysql database the ip seems to change. What is the problem?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.135:3306/kinderopvang";
String userName = "wim";
String password = "wim";
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
```

This is the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'wim'@'192.168.0.205' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4686)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1304)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at controller.db.GebruikerDatabankSQL.testGebruikerDatabankSQL(GebruikerDatabankSQL.java:31)
at run.NewMain.main(NewMain.java:341)
```

As you can see I want to connect to ip address 192.168.0.135 but i connect to 192.168.0.205 which is my own ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to give the permission for remote access

grant permission first using this way

```
GRANT ALL ON kinderopvang.* to 'wim'@'192.168.0.135' IDENTIFIED BY 'wim'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Since the question uses database name 'kinderopvang', username 'wim' and password 'wim', it is better to use the same values in the answer. Suggesting the use of `root` user for accessing an application specific database is dangerous.

Comment: @Eternal-Learner I just an example to try this way.Its not write to spoon feed users with exact code.But thanks you have modified it.

Comment: unfortunately, the example would also work. An ignorant novice may end up using it (without knowing the implications), since SO is rated very highly by google.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed my answer but forgot to post it!

Answer (score 0):

It says the user wim@yourIP doesn't have access to the otherIP,
Therefore you have to give permission for remote access.

Answer (score 0):

[@javaBeginner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19656831/1031945) gave you the solution, but I am posting this answer to your question.

> I want to connect to ip adres 192.168.0.135 but i connect to 192.168.0.205 which is my own ip adress

The error

> Access denied for user 'wim'@'192.168.0.205' (using password: YES)

**It means that your machine (IP `192.168.0.205`) has not enough privilege to access the database `kinderopvang` of machine (IP `192.168.0.135`).**

This happens because of one of the following reasons.

1. User name is wrong.
2. Password is wrong.
3. You do not have enough privilege to access the database.